# Warehouse restriction to user in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

On odoo 10 enterprise, we want to limit users to only have access to products and quantities of a specific warehouse location, so that they cannot see products and quantities of other warehouse locations.

Have installed "Warehouse Restriction" module ( https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/warehouse_stock_restrictions/) on top of the native installation. I see that it has been downloaded many times. I was wondering if this module works properly?

Followed setup instructions on https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/warehouse_stock_restrictions/, ticked "restrict locations" and specified locations in the just appeared tab, But testing the user accounts, still they CAN see all products and quantities.

How to setup this limiting feature for users?

Comment: you can use security group